# I am using Linkify.WEB_URLS to linkify URLs in text view, but it looks like there's a bug with the regex

Tags: android, linkify

I am using Linkify.WEB_URLS to linkify URLs in text view, but it looks like there's a bug with  the regex.

If I am doing this

```
noteView.setText("go to the website blabla (https://www.test.com/)");
Linkify.addLinks(noteView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

It linkifies the closing ) too

Here's how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmOuT.png

Is there a way to fix that other than rewriting the regex completely and using the fixed one in my code? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the closing parenthesis out of your link would be to put spaces around it, like this:

```
noteView.setText("go to the website blabla( http://www.test.com/ )");
```

You could also make the link look however you like if you wrap it in an anchor tag and then call Html.fromHTML on it, as shown in the solution here:  [How can I make links in fromHTML clickable? (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303160/how-can-i-make-links-in-fromhtml-clickable-android)

Comment: The problem is that I am formatting user content and can't modify it in any way. I've seen that just adding a space at the end of every text snippet solves the bug, but that is not something that I can do

Comment: The 'add-white-space' work-around worked for me even if I added it to the very end of the text:
`String text = "blabla(http://www.test.com/)"; noteView.setText(text + " ");`