# html.fromhtml highlights links not working

Tags: android

I have a link inside a Textview, when i'd clicked it work(open the link) but do not highlight color arround the link before open.

that's my code:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a> example of link");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">This is a link</a>"));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

From [Gunnar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303160/how-can-i-make-links-in-fromhtml-clickable-android) 's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to make it work -

```
htmlContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `android:textColorHighlight="yourColorHere"` on your `TextView`