# show clickable URL in message using StringBuilder java

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

I want to display a clickable URL in the message of android so i need your suggestion how to do that? I used Linkify but it is used for only text view but i want it in the StringBuilder.

StringBuilder shareMsgBuilder = new StringBuilder("google.com");

Comment: use `SpannableString[Builder]` and call `setSpan()` with `URLSpan` object, alsp you can use `Linkify.addLinks(Spannable text, ...)`

Comment: Look at this http://android2011dev.blogspot.jp/2013/10/open-url-linkify-text-and-spannable.html

Comment: Refer this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303160/how-can-i-make-links-in-fromhtml-clickable-android

Answer (score 1):

Define a `TextView` containing text *google.com* inside **Layout** file, and write an attribute `autoLink` and set its value `web` which will let you open the URL in browser.

```
 <TextView
      android:text="http://www.google.com"
      android:autoLink="web"/>
```

Other `autoLink` attributes are `email, phone, map`, you can also use multiple attributes in same `TextView` by separating them using `|` like `web|email|phone`.